# How can I solve $m^{2}+9m-1 = n^{2}$ for an integer?

Tags: number-theory

to be honest , I can't solve this by factorization or completing the Square without any guess.

$m^{2}+9m-1 = n^{2}$

$  \left ( 2m+9 \right )^{2} - 85  = \left (2n  \right )^{2}$

and set $ \ \  2m+9 =a  \  , 2n=b $

then   $a^{2} -b^{2} =85 $

and finally verify a composite of 85?

or have you any better idea to solve this question? Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that $$85=5\cdot 17$$

Comment: Could you please show me another one solution for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: You can set $a+b$ to any of the divisors $\pm1,\pm5,\pm17,\pm85$ of $85$, and $a-b$ to the co-factor. If and only if this produces even $b$ and odd $a$, you have a solution for $m,n$

Comment: In this moment i have no other solution

Answer (score 4):

What you did was right. Keep going and get $(2m+9+n)(2m+9-n)=85$

Now check for $2m+9+n=\pm1,\pm5,\pm17,\pm85.$ Do this and you will get $m=-26,-10,1,17$, with $n=-42,-6,6,42$ respectively.